# Override a method from library to different projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shared-libraries, overriding

I have my main code set up as a project with two other projects (lite and pro) referencing it.

This is how I want the `Quiz` class to look for lite:

```
class Quiz {
    public Quiz {
        object1();
        object2();
        object3();
        object4();
    }
}
```

This is how I want the `Quiz` class to look for pro:

```
class Quiz {
    public Quiz {
        object1();
        object2();
        object3();
        object4();
        object5();
        object6();
        object7();
        object8();
    }
}
```

To accomplish this, do I need to set class `Quiz` to abstract in the library and then define them however I would like to in the lite and pro projects?  Or should I define the library as the first `Quiz` example above and then try to overwrite it somehow in the pro version?

**EDIT**

Based on a comment below, here is a snippet of the actual code.

```
public class Quiz {

    ArrayList<Question> exodus = new ArrayList<Question>(200);

    public Quiz() {

        exodus.add(new Question("Aaron", "Abraham", "Jacob", "Joseph", 0, "What was the name of Moses' brother?", -1, "Exodus 7:1-2"));
        exodus.add(new Question("5", "10", "7", "12", 1, "How many plagues did God send on Egypt?", -1, "Exodus 7-12"));
        exodus.add(new Question("Pharaoh's maid", "Pharaoh's wife", "Pharaoh's daughter", "Pharaoh's mother", 2, "Who found baby Moses in a basket along the riverside of the Nile river?", -1, "Exodus 2:3-5"));
        exodus.add(new Question("Hail", "Frogs", "Boils", "Flies", 1, "What was the 2nd plague?", -1, "Exodus 8:2"));
        exodus.add(new Question("Darkness for 3 days", "All water turns to blood", "Boils", "Flies", 3, "What was the 4th plague?", -1, "Exodus 8:24"));
        exodus.add(new Question("Frogs", "Boils", "Hail", "Lice", 1, "What was the 6th plague?", -1, "Exodus 9:10"));
        exodus.add(new Question("Boils", "All livestock dies", "Lice", "Locusts", 3, "What was the 8th plague?", -1, "Exodus 10:14"));
        exodus.add(new Question("Darkness for 3 days", "Death of firstborn", "All water turns to blood", "All livestock dies", 1, "What was the 10th plague?", -1, "Exodus 12:29"));
}
```

Comment: Code isn't very clear. Are "public Quiz {" actually refering to constructors? (public Quiz() {) and you are initializing different objects in that constructor?

Comment: I added in a snippet of the actual code to help clarify.  In the actual ````Quiz```` class there is about 500 ````Question```` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to constructors as the question is not clear

```
class Quiz {
    public Quiz (){
        object1();
        object2();
        object3();
        object4();
    }
}

class QuizForPro extends Quiz{
    public QuizForPro() {
        super();
        object5();
        object6();
        object7();
        object8();
    }
}
```

You can extend the `Quiz` in your other library `Pro` and then provide a *more specialized* implementation that makes sense to your library. This is why specialization is available in OOP, so that you can extend the parent class functionality and provide some additional behavior (which in your case is adding more elements in arraylist).

**UPDATE:**
Looking at the snippet you are using the constructor to add questions, which would be a bad place to do.

You should provide a method something like `addQuestion(...), removeQuestion(...), clearQuestions(...)`. Those will make more sense here.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I could just define the ````Quiz```` class in my library how I want my lite version to look like and then in my pro version I can extend ````Quiz````, call ````super()```` and add more objects.  That way my lite project I won't have to add anything to.  Does that sound right?  I will go integrate that and report back the result.

Comment: Yes that seems correct. Your question was not completely clear to me so had to assume some details. But that seems right.

Comment: It is asking to import ````import matt.lyons.bibletrivia.Question;```` and ````import matt.lyons.bibletrivia.Quiz;```` to get it to compile.  I'm assuming this is fine to do this?

Comment: Yes importing is required for the class to compile. Do that. And you should probably read some basic java tutorials too.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Narendra's answer and it should work. However i would guess the below design should suffice. {Again depends on the actual requirements of the end product}

Quiz as class with the array list definition to store the data but no initialization in constructor. It provides methods to add bunch of questions.

```
public final class Quiz {
  ArrayList<Question> exodus = new ArrayList<Question>(200);
  public Quiz() { }
  public addQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
     // ... implementation here ... 
  }
}
```

I will have the lite and pro just as member initializations in the client class or provide a QuizHelper class which creates these 2 type of objects and returns it.